# How to use Redux Saga debounce but fetch first instead of waiting for n milliseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Is there a way in `redux-saga` to only fetch one time during for example in 5 seconds?

I know that there's  `debounce`  function:

```
yield debounce(5000, 'SAMPLE_ACTION', actionToFetchFirst)
```

but what I want is for it to fetch first rather than waiting for 5 seconds for initial fetch

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. So when a user types 's' you immediately want to search using the value `s` and then when the user types `e` you want to ignore searching for `se` because you want a reverse debounce?

Comment: yeah that's my case exactly...

Comment: I also updated the debounce example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want is for it to fetch first rather than waiting for 5 seconds for initial fetch

You can specify `leading=true` in [`lodash.debounce` options](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce):

```
lodash.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

> [options.leading=false] (boolean): Specify invoking on the leading edge of the timeout.

```
lodash.debounce(5000, 'SAMPLE_ACTION', { leading: true });
```

Or just add a condition, something like:

```
if (input.length > 1) fetchDebounced();
else fetch();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you are looking for is called throttle meaning that in the timespan of 5 seconds this action will only be called once, if so you can use lodash throttle func for this
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle

Comment: Thats not  throttling. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/